Migrate Play Services Auth from 20.4.1 to 20.5+
I try to implements Google Sign In inside my android application
I found this tutorial (https://github.com/philipplackner/ComposeGoogleSignInCleanArchitecture) which works pretty well
But, as soon as I update the dependency com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth, it doesn't work anymore and I get the following error:
com.google.android.gms.internal.auth-api.zbaz could not execute call because it requires feature (auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, 8).
    com.google.android.gms.common.api.UnsupportedApiCallException: Missing Feature{name=auth_api_credentials_begin_sign_in, version=8}
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zaL(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:12)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.zabq.zap(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:3)
    at com.google.android.gms.common.api.internal.GoogleApiManager.handleMessage(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:64)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
    at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)


Changelog (https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) isn't really helpful...
Do you know what's the breaking change between 20.4.1 and 20.5+? Because I don't see what to change...

Thanks!
